# Apache fica muito lento

Tags: apache, centos

Meu apache começa a ficar lento do nada, passa 5 minutos depois que eu ligo ele e os usuarios começam a acessar o site e o apache começa a ficar lento, utilizei o comando TOP no centos pra ver os processos e o resultado é este abaixo(nao colei tudo se nao iria ficar muito grande):

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
7461 mysql     20   0 2664688 266500   7240 S   6.8  3.3   1:55.17 mysqld
14200 apache    20   0  607620  17904   4372 R   2.5  0.2   0:13.45 httpd
14398 apache    20   0  607488  17900   4344 R   2.5  0.2   0:12.49 httpd
13806 apache    20   0  607908  19852   5980 R   2.2  0.2   0:19.31 httpd
13808 apache    20   0  607948  18408   4536 R   2.2  0.2   0:17.65 httpd
13847 apache    20   0  607488  17940   4400 R   2.2  0.2   0:16.45 httpd
13994 apache    20   0  607488  17888   4300 R   2.2  0.2   0:14.08 httpd
14019 apache    20   0  607488  17888   4312 R   2.2  0.2   0:13.89 httpd
14035 apache    20   0  607620  17900   4304 R   2.2  0.2   0:13.69 httpd
14037 apache    20   0  607488  17892   4332 R   2.2  0.2   0:13.37 httpd
14054 apache    20   0  607488  17892   4316 R   2.2  0.2   0:13.35 httpd
14073 apache    20   0  607572  17900   4316 R   2.2  0.2   0:13.41 httpd
14106 apache    20   0  607488  17928   4352 R   2.2  0.2   0:13.28 httpd
14180 apache    20   0  607488  17896   4320 R   2.2  0.2   0:13.05 httpd
14212 apache    20   0  607832  18228   4516 R   2.2  0.2   0:13.27 httpd
```

Existe alguma solução pra fazer ele parar de ficar tao lento assim?
a configuracao do meu servidor é:

Centos 7
8GB de Memoria
4 vCPUs

Já setei 256MB, 1GB no memory_limit e tambem nao adiantou nada.
tambem coloquei as seguintes configuracoes no httpd do apache e tambem nao adiantou nada:

```
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 5
MaxKeepAliveRequests 500
HostnameLookups Off
```

Meu servidor recebe em média 5 mil acessos por hora.
alguem poderia me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aconselho a trocar o apache por Nginx ... ou então usar o nginx como proxy do apache. vai ganhar mais desempenho, tanto na resposta como no consumo.

Caso não seja possivel (dependendo da aplicação), precisa ver várias outras configurações do sistema e otimizar ele.

Pode ser que o max file opens (config do kernel) do seu SO esteja muito baixo ... tem vários fatores que influenciam.

Comment: vou tentar usar o nginx pra ver se da certo, obrigado.